# How to set the params react router not misunderstand with the static router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How to set the params react router so that it does not misunderstand with the static router below, I set so when you enter the static router it is misunderstood as the params pass!

```
<AppRoute exact path="/:category/:slug" layout={PublicLayout} component={Product} />
<AppRoute exact path="/dashboard/products" layout={DashboardLayout} component={DashboardProducts} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Switch` (*which stops after the first match*) and place the fixed path first

```
<Switch>
    <AppRoute exact path="/dashboard/products" layout={DashboardLayout} component={DashboardProducts} />
    <AppRoute exact path="/:category/:slug" layout={PublicLayout} component={Product} />
</Switch>
```